# How to automate grabcut algorithm in opencv python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I have used the interactive grabcut.py available at opencv.

Visit: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/python/grabcut.py

I successfully segmented one image  by drawing rectangle with the mouse and subsequently segmenting it.

But i want to apply the same segmentation (i.e i want the program to take the same rectangle values) for a set of 10 images instead of drawing the rectangles individually on all of the 10 images.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: You can create a `for` loop to iterate the task over all your images for the same rectangle values

Comment: thankyou, but where exactly  do i add the for loop in the given code(in the link)

Comment: You have to modify this code. Pass the same rectangle values in a for loop and perform grabcut